What is the authencity of these hadiths on Abdaal (Substitutes) of Syria?
I'm a revert. So naturally, my knowledge is very limited. However, the Islam I came to is completely different from the one that people I live with practice. They have weird beliefs and Aqeedah like believing in 40 Abdaal that have powers given to them by Allah, and as soon as one of them dies, another person takes its place and becomes the new Abdaal. Out of curiosity, I asked one of them for the sources of these beliefs and he cited me this source.
I managed to find that hadith on Sunnah.com, its reference is Musnad 896:

Shuraih - i.e., bin Ubaid said:
The people of Syria were mentioned in the presence of Ali bin Abi Talib (رضي الله عنه) when he was in Iraq. They said: Curse them, O Ameer al-Mu`mineen. He said: No, I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say: “The abdal (people who are close to Allah) will be in Syria, and they will be forty men. Every time one of them dies, Allah will replace him with another man. By virtue of them rain is sent and through them victory is achieved against the enemy and punishment is warded off from the people of Syria.

It is graded weak by Darussalam. The source clearly rejects that and gives reason for it. However, their argument heavily relies on the assumption that in the Musnad Ahmad, the takhrij about the hadith being weak is not from Imam Ahmad ibn Hanbal himself. Probably suggesting that it is added by the publisher or something. See the image below.

Question: Is it true that this comment is not by Imam Ahmad? What is really the authenticity of these hadiths and why are there some scholars who seem to not think these stories are fabrication (like here). And also what are good hadiths or verses from the Qur'an to counter this belief if this is fabrication?
Jazakallahu Khayran!

The comment on the authenticity of the hadith is not by Imam Ahmad, it is by the researchers of the committee of scholars which was consulted by the publisher Darussalam. This is mentioned under the publishers note. The comment is not found in the original text or in many of the editions of Musnad Ahmad published by other publishers.
The comment is correct in that the chain is da'eef (weak) as there is an interruption in the chain, since there is disagreement on whether the transmitter Shuraih met Ali ibn Abi Talib. The hadith has been weakened by a number of scholars such as al-Albani and al-Arnaa’oot.
However there are some who accept a hadith with an interrupted chain, as long as it was reported by a truthful and reliable person. Similarly there are those who would accept a weak hadith if its meaning is corroborated by other reports, and in this case there are other corroborating reports.
The general concept of saints is accepted in Islam. What is problematic is to assume a certain person to be a saint when there is evidence to the contrary, or to venerate a saint in a forbidden way.
You can also read What is exactly meant by كرامت/keramet.

That you said they have weird beliefs and Aqeedah like believing in 40 Abdaal that have powers given to them by Allah, and as soon as one of them dies, another person takes its place and becomes the new Abdaal, to Shia believing in Abdaal in never considered weird, although many Shia Muslims might not be so familiar with Ahadeeth about them. Let me refer to several resources on this, though you should use a translator to read them: here, here, and here. A single Hadeeth might be week, but there are a number of them in different resources. All-in-all, we believe Abdaal exist, but not necessarily limited to 40 in number, not limited to men as there can be women among them, not limited to Shaam (which can include Palestine, and not necessarily Syria, if I'm not wrong), and they will be the top figures in the army of Imam Mahdi PBUH when he upraises, at the time their number will be 313 if I may conclude the Ahadeeth such.
